# Windows Driver Developement Local debugging questions.

Tags: windows, debugging, driver, local

Here is the scenario.
I am on windows 8 Machine/ Also have tried this on windows 7 machine.

I working on a driver(mirror driver/Remote display Driver). I should say I am going to start working on it as I am stuck.

So I followed the MSDN example of KmdfSmall

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx

I got the driver code compiled. Got the remote debugging also going.

I do not see any of the debug messages on the host( I have set the  register IHVDRIVER to 0x8
I also set the DEFAULT to 0xf to be able to use DbgPrint

Further more. My real goal is start my driver as a service

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9504/Driver-Development-Part-1-Introduction-to-Drivers

And I want to test it on the LOCAL machine. I do not want to have a target and host to debug. Plain oldschool single machine.

Questions

1)  When  service starts the driver via `CreateService` and `OpenService`, does it call the DriverEntry function or does it wait until someone user level app uses the driver.

2) When I run the app to load the driver as a server where would the  `DbgPrintEx`  suppose to print
DebugView or WinDbg or else where.

3) If I am using

```
CreateService
```

does my sys file has to be in windows/system32/drivers folder ? I read somewhere that in 64 bit machine `CreateService` only loads from system folder.

4) when I start it as a service am I suppose to see it on the task Manager

5)If `DriverEntry` is called to init a driver,  can it be called again or it has to wait until it unloads ? So I load my driver and forget to gracefully unload it and run my program again will it call `DriverEntry` ?

I know there are a lot of questions here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KMDF driver cannot be installed using old style API. Check [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/NONPNP-5fb0fa62/sourcecode?fileId=51270&pathId=1045795838) from MSDN.

You also need to think about what kind of driver it is, filter driver or actual device driver etc.

> 1) When service starts the driver via CreateService and OpenService,
>   does it call the DriverEntry function or does it wait until someone
>   user level app uses the driver.

As soon as the driver is loaded, its `DriverEntry` routine is called.

> 2) When I run the app to load the driver as a server where would the
>   DbgPrintEx suppose to print DebugView or WinDbg or else where.

When none of DebugView or WinDbg is running, the output is lost and not printed/logged anywhere.

> 3) If I am using `CreateService` does my sys file has to be in windows/system32/drivers
>   folder ? I read somewhere that in 64 bit machine CreateService only
>   loads from system folder.

Newer windows has such kind of restriction.

> 4) when I start it as a service am I suppose to see it on the task
>   Manager

Kernel drivers are not listed in task manager as they are actually part of OS not a separate application. However, if you have user level service, it will be listed in task manager when its running.

> 5)If DriverEntry is called to init a driver, can it be called again or
>   it has to wait until it unloads ? So I load my driver and forget to
>   gracefully unload it and run my program again will it call DriverEntry ?

`DriverEntry` is called each time the driver is loaded. If the driver is demand load, it will run each time the driver is loaded/started, even if driver does not unload gracefully (e.g. leaking memory/locks etc). But you may end up in unstable system and BSOD if driver doesn't unload neatly.